# Send 2 parameters with the same name with a laravel api

Tags: laravel

I have an api or I send an array as url? name[0]=test&name[1]=test1

I am asked to be sent as url? name=test&name=test1

but I don’t see how doing resquest cancels the first parameter:/

Comment: I believe you need to do `name[]=test&name[]=test1`

Comment: Or you should make it a post request and send it like a json :)